# Eclipse is converting from \uXXXX to UTF-8 Characters

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, internationalization

I am using eclipse for a project. My propertied file is set to use ISO-8859-1, but whenever I enter a `\uXXXX` string it converts it to the UTF-8 character.

Are there any preferences that must be set so that this doesn't happen?

I am using globalyzer to make my files.

Comment: i am not. I thought I was at first, but when I tried to commit my file all of the lines were "changed". my file file had characters and the other had `\uXXXX` strings

Answer (score -1):

I was using Globalyzer. Window->Preferences->Globalyzer->Resource File Editors

uncheck "convert uXXXX to unicode"...

you can also go to formatting option and check "convert unicode to uXXXX"

hope this helps anyone with the same problem